# Date of when a Field was populated

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splist

Is it possible to get the date of when a choice field was populated? I'm asking because we have a SharePoint list which is automatically populated by an automation and the entries are later reviewed by one of our team members. Whoever is reviewing the entry add his name to the entry through a choice field, and I'd like to get the date when the 'Reviewed By' field is populated. I thought about using a calculated column but I'm not sure what formula would get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use "Modified" date column if the item will not be changed anymore. If you want something more specific you have to use a Power Automate flow.

Comment: I would add a Date and Time column like [ReviewedDate] and add a form validation that it's required when [Reviewed By] is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Unfortunately, I'm not able to use the 'Modified' field because I've a flow running after each entry is reviewed and the dates changes.

@MatiurRahman, Would it require the Power Apps to make it work or is it something I can do on the List settings? Sorry I'm asking a silly question, I'm quite new to all these tools.

Comment: If you're using SharePoint list forms, you can force [Reviewed By] user to enter a date by using List Settings->Validation Settings. However, if you're using PowerApps Form to update the list, you can do that on PowerApps as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, I would assume a Power Automate which is triggered when the item is created/modified. Use condition to check if it is reviewed(reviewed by column has value ), if yes, just log the time to another list or update a current item column, both shall work.